# Woocommerce. Как ускорить запрос "положить в корзину"?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У меня есть интернет магазин [www.haifa-flower.co.il](https://www.haifa-flower.co.il/) .

Он сделан на wordpress + woocommerce.

По просьбе клиента я переделал обычный функционал "положить в корзину" под AJAX.

В общем все работает но меня не устраивает скорость операции. Уходит от 1,1 до 2 сек.

Comment: Надо профилировать сайт: https://kagg.eu/profiling-wordpress-sites-meetup-materials/

Comment: в итоге вам удалось решить проблему? а то у меня подобная беда в наличии